# Laravel generate excel from query returns an error using maatwebsite

Tags: php, excel, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

Basically i got a query and the results will be created as an excel file. Here is my code

```
$data = \DB::table('checkers')
        ->where('remarks_id',2)
        ->join('schedules','schedules.id','=','checkers.schedule_id')
        ->join('teachers','schedules.teacher_id','=','teachers.id')
        ->join('subject_codes','subject_codes.id','=','schedules.subject_code_id')
        ->join('remarks','remarks.id','=','checkers.remarks_id')
        ->where('checkers.created_at', '=>', $request->from)
        ->where('checkers.created_at', '=<', $request->to)
        ->select('teachers.fullname','subject_codes.subject_description','remarks.remarks_desc','checkers.created_at')
        ->get(); 

        $data = $data->map(function ($x) {
            return json_decode(json_encode($x), true);
        })->all();

        // dd($data);

        Excel::create('report', function($excel) use($data) {
            $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) use($data) {
            });
        })->export('xls');
```

when i do `dd($data)

```
array:2 [
  0 => {#294
    +"fullname": "Edcel Pagagao"
    +"subject_description": "Capstone 1"
    +"remarks_desc": "No Teacher Around"
    +"created_at": "2020-01-30 00:00:00"
  }
  1 => {#298
    +"fullname": "Edcel Pagagao"
    +"subject_description": "Capstone 1"
    +"remarks_desc": "No Teacher Around"
    +"created_at": "2020-01-27 00:00:00"
  }
]
```

Which is what the docs said https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/array.html based on 2.x version

But i still got error `continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2`

Comment: Is there some code inside `->sheet(...` ?

Comment: what you mean sir @FelippeDuarte

Comment: I mean if this is your real code or if there is more code where you actually put the `$data` inside your sheet.

Comment: i am using `use($data)`

Comment: why you do this part `return json_decode(json_encode($x), true);`

Comment: for encoding the array based on the docs

Comment: they are passing array data so you can change collection to array check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you link [Link](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/2.1/export/array.html) first example says you need to pass **array** data like below

```
$array_data = array(
    array('data1', 'data2'),
    array('data3', 'data4')
 );
$sheet->fromArray($array_data);
```

you can change collection as array using **`toArray()`**

```
$data = \DB::table('checkers').....->select('teachers.fullname','subject_codes.subject_description',
'remarks.remarks_desc','checkers.created_at')
->get()
->toArray();
```

Comment: i tried it sir but it says `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string"`

Comment: can you show me `dd($data)`   before deocde or encode  ??

Comment: can we discuss here sir? I really need help with this https://join.slack.com/t/vue-vmr4432/shared_invite/enQtOTAyMjIzODM5NzQ3LTgyY2Q2ODA1ZjRmNTdkZjAwZmMyYjc3NWYzOGRiNWU5NjEwNWYzM2UyZmE0ODk5OTdhY2NkMWZmM2Q2YTBjYjA